# Is it a security issue to show the complete bank account number in your payment methods?

Tags: web-application

While websites like [amazon](https://www.amazon.de/gp/css/account/cards/view.html) and most others do not show your bank account number (except for the last few digits) when displaying the details of your current payment methods (using direct debit), others like [car2go](https://www.car2go.com/DE/de/myaccount/#/payment-profiles-private.html) show your complete account number. Is there any problem with showing the complete details?

Comment: Not show your account number in list of payment options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probabbly is:

An account number (complete of course) it's a medium-high level information.
So showing it completely may be a chance for a attacker to steal it, as for example, using a remote-VNC malware.

In most of cases, having only the account number won't mean a risk of being a fraud victim, as it requires some other info (as CVV, PIN-code, or any other additional security measure). But it's a leak of information.

Any platform with a good security should not show the complete account number if it is not needed.

Comment: Did you mean "should not show" ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Your account number is on every check you write anyway. If the web page is secure, then it's far safer than a paper copy of the same digits. This system with checks has worked for decades with minimal and known/accepted risks. It may seem scary because it's on the internet, but i bet most folks irrationally worry less about that when handing checks to a cashier or waiter...